# Splitting list by value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, split

I want to be able to split a list, like `str.split()`. When I have this list:

```py
['one', 'two', '.', 'three', '.', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

I want to get this result:

```py
[['one', 'two'], ['three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

I have looked for solutions, but they produce this result:

```py
[['one', 'two', '.'], ['three', '.'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

which is not the result that I want. I have not tried to implement this myself because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: please make an attempt, and provide your attempt before asking

Comment: itertools.groupby is made for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lst = ['one', 'two', '.', 'three', '.', 'four', 'five', 'six']
result = []
tmp = []
for entry in lst:
  if entry != '.':
    tmp.append(entry)
  else:
    result.append(tmp)
    tmp = []
result.append(tmp)
print(result)
```

output

```
[['one', 'two'], ['three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```